# Concatenation of three integers in C

Tags: integer, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have to enter the 3-bit integer (100-999) and calculate the sum of each bit.The input format is 1  2  3 and output should be 6.
I m thinking about concatenating these three integer variables in a string and then convert that string in int and add them. But I am getting how to concatenate these three variables. If you help me i will be highly thankful to you.

```
int main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3, temp, digit, sum = 0;
    char str1[20], str2[20], str3[20];
    printf("Enter the number \n");
    scanf("%ld", &n1);
    scanf("%ld", &n2);
    scanf("%ld", &n3)

    sprintf(str1,"%d",n1);
    sprintf(str2,"%d",n2);
    sprintf(str3,"%d",n3);
    strcat(str1,str2,str3);

}
```

Comment: 100 isn't a 3 bit integer

Comment: then what is it , it is a 3 digit number , 100-999 all are